# Docker error when trying to pull image

Tags: docker, docker-image

Getting this error while pulling images.

`failed to register layer: Error processing tar file(exit status 1): archive/tar: invalid tar header.`

I've just re-installed docker and am now trying to pull some images. Earlier was no getting this kind of errors.

Using stable version of docker.

Any help on this.

Comment: Which OS? Linux, Mac, Windows?

Comment: Using CentOS linux

Comment: see https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/4437 and https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/15561

Comment: Could you attach the command that gives you this error?

Comment: docker pull jenkins...  it failed while extracting the image.and pull failed

Comment: I got same error while loading image.
:$ docker load -i testimage.tar
Output:
Error processing tar file(exit status 1): archive/tar: invalid tar header